# Populating a QTreeView on an existing application with a QFilesystemModel

Tags: c++, qt4

I have an existing Qt application with buttons and other widgets on it. I would like to add a QTreeView (or QTreeWidget) to the application, and populate it with a QFilesystemModel.

I have seen examples and read the Qt documentation on using QTreeView and QTreeWidgets but they are always just creating a standalone QTreeView on its own, which I can replicate fine.

I used QtDesigner to add a QTreeView on my application, but i cannot work out how to use the QFilesystemModel to populate it.

How do I access the QTreeView on my application and set its model to the QFilesystemModel?

Comment: Using a QTreeView, you can access its setModel() method.
Have you tried with 

    QFileSystemModel fs = new QFileSystemModel();
    ui->your_qtreeview_name->setModel(fs);

?

Comment: @BiG - "ui->your_qtreeview_name->setModel(fs);"  that's the bit I'm having difficulty with..  Is 'ui' the top level QWidget? or is it equivalent to 'this'

Comment: Mmm, strange...Yes, 'ui' is, in a sense, what you said. You should see it as a paremeter passed to your MainWindow's constructor. As an example, I have something like this in my project:

`MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow){`


    `ui->setupUi(this);`

`//...`

`}`